# couldn't parse post string into array

Tags: php, ajax, post

I am trying to send my form data to php method below is the code:

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(event){
            var data = $.param($("#form").serializeArray());
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "customers.php",
                data: data,
                });
            request.done(function() {
            $( "#message" ).html("Record entered");
                });
            });
         });
    </script>
```

So the above code is making a string of name and value.

I would like to use that string in my php method but was unable to do that.

```
  <?php 
      if(isset($_POST['customername'])){
          $arg = $_POST['customername'];
          $customer->Add_Customer($arg);
      }
      ?>
```

as you can see my method requires an array basically a numeric array

like : john,23,england,76001

Can anyone please guide me how can i do that i dont wanna send it via GET.

Thanks

Comment: what the output of `$_POST`.

Comment: it is customername=abc&phone=123&address=xyz

Comment: what's the problem here? also, can you do a var_dump($_POST); ?

Comment: then you can get your data from post ? where is the issue.

Comment: actually i want $_POST a numeric array so that i can pass it to my function. the parse_str is making an assocative array

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
        var data = $.param($("#form").serializeArray());
```

to

```
        var data = $("#form").serializeArray();
```

Comment: Thats doing the same thing also.

Answer (score 0):

I send arrays from `js` to `php` on this way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){
//Your vars
var data=new Array();
data[0]=#('#input1').val();
data[1]=#('#anotherInput1').val();

$.post('customers.php',data,function(data){
//Shows response
alert(data);
});
return false;
});

});//Ready
```

Php:

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['data'];
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
echo "$data[$i] <br>";
?>
```

---

Maybe is the old way, but it still working for me. Hope it helps. It's just an idea for `post`.